# Save Mathematica presenter notebook as PDF?

Tags: slideshows

I have been applying Mathematica presenter notebook as a primary tool for presentation. I found it to be an efficient alternative to LaTex, and a cleaner alternative to PowerPoint. 
However, when I project my screen with a projector, there are always zooming or resolution problems. I wonder if there is any way that I can save my presenter notebook to a portable format, such as PDF?
Many thanks.

Comment: You can File / Save As... and select PDF. But of course you will lose all interactive ability, which is what I think is the best part of presenter notebooks. What version are you using? Version 12 seems to do a better job with handling changes to the zoom % dropdown while presenting.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to save as PDF. However, the purpose is to have a portable PDF slides, like those generated by LaTex. The PDF generated by Mathematica loses most of the formatting, which can hardly be used for presentation purposed.